# Can not join windows 2008 r2 domain machine to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain

So we one machine that we can not join to the domain. It is a windows 2008 r2 box. We have created and added other machines to the domain. When attempting to join we are getting the error message that it can be no longer reached. 

We have checked: 
Hosts file
Specified the domain suffix
validated dns entries
nslookup of domain shows all dcs 
migrated machine to a different host
Removed virtual network adapter and readded / reconfigured
shut off ipv6
tried restarting of workstation, browser and server services

Any thing else any one can think of?

Comment: Oh and we checked Time

Comment: What's output of?:

(Get-ADForest).ForestMode &            
(Get-ADDomain).DomainMode

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have any 3rd party firewall installed with network protection on it?
- Rename the computer to different hostname and then try to join domain?
- Is Client for Microsoft Networks installed?
- Are you able to ping the 2008 R2 VM IP from the domain controllers? And vice-versa, can you ping all the domain controllers from the 2008 R2 VM?